# Failed to load module 'canberra-gtk-module' proxychains

Tags: 20.04, firefox

I'm trying to connect to Firefox using proxychains. Everytime I try to connect it gives me this error:

> failed to load module 'canberra-gtk-module'

I have looked at some articles and other posts, but nothing has worked so far, I downloaded several things, and I also made changes to some files, but the error keeps coming back.

Comment: Have you tried to install needed package by `sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk3-module` ? You wrote "made changes to some files" - which files were changed?

Comment: @N0rbert i already tried that command, the files i modified were proxychains.conf and /usr/bin/proxychains. I also found that the proxychain works with other commands but not with firefox.

Comment: I had the same problem, for an unrelated program. It may be looking for an older version. Try adding libcanberra-gtk-module, which also adds libcanberra-gtk0, it did the trick for me.
The clean solution would be of course to recompile from src.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by "add"?

Comment: This is also the error I now get when trying to launch Thunderbird and it happens since yesterday. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1312724/thunderbird-problems-as-of-1st-feb-2021

Comment: I meant:
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module

Answer (score 2):

It's `snap firefox`, install it with `apt get`.

The `canberra` module is then solved as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1372005/in-ubuntu-21-10-firefox-and-chromium-cannot-open-file-in-hidden-directory):

```
sudo snap remove --purge firefox
sudo apt install firefox
```