# Thunderbird problems as of 1st Feb 2021

Tags: email, thunderbird

As of today, Thunderbird wants me to create a new profile rather than show data from my existing profile. It's looking for the profile in the right place as evident in the Help - Troubleshooting menu and yet nothing appears. And I can only open TB once before having to reboot, as it comes up with

> Thunderbird is already running, but is not responding. To use
> Thunderbird, you must first close the existing Thunderbird process,
> restart your device, or use a different profile.

though there don't seem to be any processes to kill.

I have tried reinstalling but to the same effect. The version is 78.5.1 on 20.04.

Comment: Thunderbird 78.5.1 is not the current version in the Ubuntu deb repositories, nor the current Snap.

Comment: It keeps changing. I now have 78.7.0 but the result is the same. If I start it via terminal it tells me: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module". There is also a version 1:68.10.0 in the Ubuntu Software app but that's no longer compatible with my email profile.

Comment: So you seem to be running the Snap version. See if https://superuser.com/questions/1440187/thunderbird-installed-via-snap-on-ubuntu-ignores-my-profile-folder helps you.

Comment: Thank you for taking the trouble. I have uninstalled and reinstalled both versions variously. Right now, it just won't open and keeps saying Thunderbird is already running but not responding. Rebooting worked before but now only an uninstall and reinstall does. If I could keep it from doing that, I'd know how to fiddle with the profiles.ini.

Answer (score 0):

Search all your Thunderbird [Profile folder(s)](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder) for a symlink file named `lock` or `parent.lock` or `.parentlock`. Delete this file(s). Try again to open Thunderbird.

If somehow you're not able to delete this file, reboot your device. Then try the steps above again.