# In Ubuntu 21.10, Firefox and Chromium cannot open file in hidden directory

Tags: firefox, snap, chromium, hidden-files

In Ubuntu 21.10, Firefox 93.0 can't open a file in a hidden directory like `/home/alba/.toto/0000000d.html`.

(Whatever the name and content of the HTML file, you can use an empty file.)

Nor does Chromium 95.0.4638.54 snap but Dillo version 3.0.5 and Google Chrome 90.0.4430.93 can do it.

In 21.04, Firefox 93.0, Dillo 3.0.5 and Google Chrome 90.0.4430.93  can do it, only Chromium 94.0.446.71 snap cannot, so this is a regression.

Can you confirm?  Is it worth reporting a bug?  Is it Firefox or Ubuntu bug?

I found this by using Claws Mails that stores HTML mail files in `~/.claws-mail/`.

**More simply**

Checked with Ubuntu 22.04.

Take any HTML file named `index.html` that Firefox or Chromium can open.  Rename it with a leading dot `.index.html`, then Firefox or Chromium cannot open it.  Firefox error message (in window) :

```
Access to the file was denied

The file at /home/me/.index.html is not readable.

    It may have been removed, moved, or file permissions may be preventing access.
```

With or without dot, the `Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"` error also occurs in Terminal so it is probably not the cause.

```
% snap list
chromium                 101.0.4951.41
firefox                  99.0.1-1
```

`dillo` has no problem.

Comment: How are you opening the file? I am able to open an empty file `~/.toto/0000000d.html` using the `*.deb` version of Firefox 93.0 in Ubuntu 21.10. I can drag the file from Nautilus onto Firefox, and it opens. Also, I can right-click on the file and select to open the file in Firefox, and it opens.

Comment: I open the file by right clicking on it in Nautilus.

Comment: I have also tried to open in the command line `firefox /home/alba/.toto/0000000d.html`, same result.  But I see this `Gtk-Message: 22:11:44.197: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module`.

Comment: I don't have this message in 21.04.  Found this https://askubuntu.com/questions/342202/failed-to-load-module-canberra-gtk-module-but-already-installed but `sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module` does not remove the message.

Comment: `firefox ~/.toto/0000000d.html` just opens the (blank) file in Firefox for me, without errors. Try the `*.deb` version. May be the snap sand-boxing is causing this? By the way, I have `libcanberra-gtk`, `libcanberra-gtk0`, `libcanberra-gtk3-0`, and `libcanberra-gtk3-module` installed.

Comment: I have tried a third method to open the file. First I had to reinstall the menu bar in Firefox, second File > Open file or more simply `control-o`.  This methods works.  However, it does not solve the Claws Mail issue, which relies basically on the command line.  Maybe some option in the command line may solve the problem,

Comment: I have removed Firefox snap 93.0-1 rev 631 with `sudo snap remove --purge firefox` then reinstalled `sudo apt install firefox` and the problem with Firefox has vanished.  Thanks.  I suppose that the problem is that snap does not connect well to the libacanberra installed with apt.

Comment: My Chromium is also a snap and on the contrary Dillo and Google Chrome are deb.  Obviously a problem with snap,

Comment: I think that may be the case. I know that the Firefox snap allows special access to the user's home directory (outside of the sand-box). Therefore, all subdirectories in the user's home directory should also be accessible (even if they are hidden). I would open a bug report about this issue.

Comment: I rediscover the problem after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04, coming with snap Firefox.

Comment: I do not know where to report a bug.

Comment: Good to know.  I conclude that it is a snap design (or flaw depending on the point of view) since the .deb version of Firefox can open "hidden" file.  A consequence is that HTML mail attachments in `~/.claws-mail` cannot be opened.

Comment: Related https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238211/how-to-make-snaps-access-hidden-files-and-folders-in-home https://superuser.com/questions/1546550/chromium-81-wont-display-dotfiles-anymore

Comment: Existing bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapd/+bug/1607067

Answer (score 0):

For Claws-Mail, you can just create a "tmp" directory in your home directory and move the "mimetmp" directory used by Claws-Mail inside:

1. Close Claws-Mail.
2. Move the "mimetmp" directory to a non-hidden "tmp" directory:

   ```
   mkdir ~/tmp
   cd ~/.claws-mail
   mv mimetmp ../tmp
   ln -sf ../tmp/mimetmp
   ```

You can now restart Claws-Mail and open attachments with Firefox or Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

I begged [advice from the Claws-mail mailing list](https://lists.claws-mail.org/pipermail/users/2022-May/030051.html).

This should work:

```
mv .claws-mail claws-mail ; claws-mail --alternate-config-dir claws-mail
```

[Deb Ubuntu can still be installed in Ubuntu 22.04.](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04)

If the above link dies:

```
sudo snap remove firefox

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa

echo '
Package: *
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-mozillateam
Pin-Priority: 1001
' | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla-firefox

echo 'Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins:: "LP-PPA-mozillateam:${distro_codename}";' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/51unattended-upgrades-firefox

sudo apt install firefox
```

Other ways :

1. Compile Firefox from source.
2. Switch to another Linux distribution that does not force to use Snap.